# Sitecore Custom Routing (Not MVC)

Tags: asp.net, sitecore, sitecore6, asp.net-routing

I followed this [post](http://pentialized.dk/2008/11/11/sitecore-and-systemwebrouting/) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308226/sitecore-and-asp-net-mvc/1668051#1668051) in order to  test create a custom routing entry for an item. I tried to register a route in global.asax something like this...

```
 void RegisterRoutes(RouteCollection routes)
    {
        routes.RouteExistingFiles = true;
        routes.MapPageRoute("about", "about/us", "~/About/Company", false);
    }
```

but the unfortunate thing is, this results in 404. I think the asp.net routing is looking for a physical page "About/Company.aspx" where as it is more of a rendered page/link out of sitecore/content/site/about/company in the sitecore tree. 
Do you know if there is way to redirect it to a rendered sitecore url/item?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using Routing to do this is possibly not the most optimal solution.

The easiest way of mapping URLs to a specific item is by setting up Aliases. See chapter 6.1 in the [Data Definition Cookbook](http://sdn.sitecore.net/upload/sitecore6/datadefinitioncookbook-a4.pdf) for more information about Aliases.

If you need more control you could create a custom ItemResolver that can sit after the default ItemResolver in the HttpRequestBegin pipeline and can run your custom URL/item mapping.