# Sitecore.Context.User returns anonymous in web service when user is logged in

Tags: sitecore, sitecore6

The web service is listed in the `IgnoreurlPrefixes` list, which I'm guessing has something to do with it. I have another service *not* listed in that list, and it returns the logged in user. (Not to over complicate things, but it's not clear to me why I'm able to have one service be callable and another not based on whether or not it's in the `IgnorURLPrefixes` list.)

So the question is: How do I get `Sitecore.Context.User` to return the logged in user when called from a web service?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't have a Sitecore context because the requested page is ignored by Sitecore and thus not processed by it.
If you need a Sitecore context you can't have the URL listed in the `IgnorURLPrefixes` list...

Comment: Thanks.  Even wierder, then, is that some services work fine without being listed, while others throw the "Length cannot be less than zero" error.

Answer (score 0):

As another answer points out, `Siteocre.Context` is not available when the URL is listed in `IgnoreURLPrefixes`. Your best bet is to add a processor to the `httpRequestBegin` pipeline, that aborts the request before Sitecore attempts to resolve an Item. This way, the context can at least be partially available.

[Examples of doing this with MVC routes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1308226/sitecore-and-asp-net-mvc) are abundant.